# Eclipse java issue with the class path

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Im creating a message publishing application on eclipse for the minute there is no GUI involved it is just going to be running from the console. But when I compile and try to run the server class I get an error saying [image]

The weird thing is the error on server.java line 24 is just a constructor creating a message class. I asked my tutor about this and he said it was some issue with the classpath not being defined properly in the IDE. I have tried compiling it and running it from command prompt and it works find it is just an Eclipse issue I believe. I have tried looking for an answer myself online but haven't come up with anything. If anyone has come across this before, how did you solve it?

[image]

Comment: Are you initialising some static fields in Message class other than _class? This kind of error often occurs when a class can be compiled but there is an error when it is loaded. This would be the case of an exception while static field initialisation

Comment: I also suggest you to check if the version of Java you are using from the command line is the same you are using in eclipse